# Where do I find documentation and examples of the sciruby nmatrix C/C++ api?

Tags: ruby, opencv, nmatrix, sciruby

I am trying to write ruby interfaces to a piece scientific computation library I wrote. This library itself uses other open-source libraries like OpenCV, boost etc. The primary data structure my library operates on, and that is being returned by my library, is an n-dimensional array type.  Hence I was looking into which appropriate ruby objects this data type will map into. There is the native ruby array type, but I also found out the more mathematically powerful Nmatrix type.

Can someone point me to the documentation for the C/C++ api for nmatrix? Googling around for the C api docs did not help. I found some docs here http://sciruby.com/nmatrix/docs/ and the code repos on github here https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix and so far have been using the source code as the docs.

A few examples would be nice too.

Comment: You might try the Developer Guide (https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/wiki/NMatrix-Developer-Guide). The truth, however, is that much of the C/C++ API hasn't been exposed, since no one's requested it. Have you tried opening an issue in the tracker (http://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/issues)?

Comment: Yep, exactly what John said. We never had someone asking for these, so we directed our efforts elsewhere :) But please, open an issue and we'll be happy to help you with whatever you need regarding the C/C++ API!